# Gcm for offline devices

Tags: android

I am using gcm for push notifications.If device already running notifications is working well.But when I close the device (I mean offline) and meanwhile I send a push notification via gcm to device then I am turning on the device to online but notifications doesn't come.

Summary:If device offline gcm notifications is not getting. How can I resolve this problem ?

Ps:Gcm server doesn't give any error for offline devices.

I am using following php lines for send push notification:

```
$registatoin_ids=array("XXXXXXXXX");
    $message = array("message" => $this->input->post('mesaj'),"sender" => $this->input->post('gonderen'),"out_username" => $this->input->post('out_username'));
    define("GOOGLE_API_KEY", "XXXXXXXX");
    $url = 'http://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
        'data' => $message,
        'delay_while_idle' => true
    );
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization:key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type:application/json'
    );
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
```

And this is the my receiver at device:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

This is the service at device:

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
        public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
        private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
        private DatabaseHandler _db=new DatabaseHandler(this);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

        public GcmIntentService() {
            super("GcmIntentService");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
            // in your BroadcastReceiver.
            String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
            Log.w("MessageType",messageType);
            if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
                Log.w("Extras",extras.toString());
                if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
//                  sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
                } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
//                  sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
//                          extras.toString());
                // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
                } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {


                    String username="asdasd";
                    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                            .setContentTitle(extras.getString("message"))
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ribony_top_icon)
                            .setContentText("Touch")
                            .setTicker(username+" sent a message")
                            .setSound(soundUri);
                    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                    resultIntent.putExtra("username",username);
                    Log.w("Intent Extra",username);
                    resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
                    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
                    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());

                    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    if (v.hasVibrator()) {
                        v.vibrate(500);
                    }
                }
            }
            // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
            GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you put the device offline, no GCM messages will be able to be received.  To solve that, turn the device back online.  What am I missing?

Comment: Yes but when i turn the device back online gcm messages(the messages has sent when device is offline) is not receiving